# How to pass an object from one view to another in ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I still don't quite grasp how one can use information in the one cshtml file, gotten from another cshtml file. My program consists out of a gallery. When the user clicks on one of the pictures, instead of simply directing to a page containing only the image url, I would like to redirect to another view that displays the picture and information pertaining to that picture. Here is the relevant code of my faulty attempt:

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var response = client.DownloadString(Url.Action("gallery", "photo", null, Request.Url.Scheme));
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = jss.Deserialize<List<Photo>>(response);

        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult FullImage(Photo m)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@section mainContent {
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    @foreach (var photo in Model)
    {
      <li class="item">
         <a href='@Url.Action("FullImage", "Home", new {imageUrl="~/photos/" + photo.FileName, title= photo.Title, description= photo.Description})'>
             <img alt="@photo.Description" src="@Url.Content("~/photos/" + photo.FileName)" class="thumbnail-border" width="180" />
         </a>
         <span class="image-overlay">@photo.Title</span>
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
}
```

**Model:**

```
namespace PhotoGallery.Models
{
    public class Photo
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use Partial View approach.

Comment: Are the photos stored in a database? If yes, what's the primary key of your Photo table?

Comment: No database. The information of the images are stored in a json file which is deserialized to obtain each image individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind to a model by using an action link. You need to pass a primary key or a unique key to your Action, and find your Model in the Action based on the key.

As an example, you can do this in your View:

```
@section mainContent {
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    @foreach (var photo in Model)
    {
      <li class="item">
         <a href='@Url.Action("FullImage", "Home", new { fileName = photo.FileName})'>
             <img alt="@photo.Description" src="@Url.Content("~/photos/" + photo.FileName)" class="thumbnail-border" width="180" />
         </a>
         <span class="image-overlay">@photo.Title</span>
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
}
```

Then, in your Action, you'll have:

```
public ActionResult FullImage(string fileName)
{
    // Example of some code to get the photo from the repository. It's better to use a photoID instead of the fileName.
    var photo = db.Photos.FindPhoto(fileName);
    return View();
}
```